# Gnuplot: get disabled plots in script

Tags: gnuplot

In some gnuplot terminals (e.g., qt and wxt), there is the possibility to interactively disable certain plots by clicking with the mouse their entry in the key. Is there a possibility to retrieve the disabled plots in any way in the gnuplot script itself?

Comment: So, you interactively disable them in the plot by double clicking on their key entry. You can retrieve them by double clicking again. I don't understand why exactly you want to retrieve them via script? What is your expectation? Something like a `replot`, but with all the disabled plots again? Just run the script again and you'll have them back. Could you please explain in more detail what's behind your question?

Comment: @theozh I don't see what's unclear about the question. I'd like to have the state of the activated/deactivated plots available in the script, e.g. in a key-binding.

Comment: ok, sorry, then this was a misinterpretation between "retrieve" and "restore". I am not aware that there is an accessible variable which holds the disabled or active plots. The variable `GPVAL_LAST_PLOT` holds the last plot command, but the value will not change if you have interactively disabled some of the plots.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is `toggle`.

```
gnuplot> help toggle

 Syntax:
       toggle {<plotno> | "plottitle" | all}

 This command has the same effect as left-clicking on the key entry for a plot
 currently displayed by an interactive terminal (qt, wxt, x11). If the plot is
 showing, it is toggled off;  if it is currently hidden, it is toggled on.
 `toggle all` acts on all active plots, equivalent to the hotkey "i".
 `toggle "title"` requires an exact match to the plot title.  `toggle "ti*"`
 acts on the first plot whose title matches the characters before the final '*'.
 If the current terminal is not interactive, the toggle command has no effect.
```

You could bind the toggle commands to hot-keys:

```
bind '1' 'toggle 1'
bind '2' 'toggle 2'
bind '3' 'toggle 3'
```

Comment: Thank you, but the `toggle` command does the opposite: it enables/disables the plot. Rather, I want to retrieve the state of that plot. Something like `bind '1' 'plot 1 visible/invisible'`, where the RHS obviously depends on what I am looking for.